# What is the I/O in explanation process.nextTick and setImmediate?

Tags: node.js

I read explanation about them and `process.nextTick` fires before Input/Output operations and `setImmediate` - after I/O operations, so. I understand that `process.nextTick` fires before all async actions and `setImmediate` fires after it but before `setTimeout`'s and before `setInterval`'s. Can someone explain and provide example - what mean `I/O` operations in this explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe to you what this are.

Suppose this is queue . which have three function in event loop to execute.

```
a , b , c
```

So queue is FIFO so first come first server , THat means a will execute then b, then c.
So what this two function do is this.
when you use

`process.nextTick` , when you run this the new process is added to the event loop and that added immediately behind the current process is executing.

that means.

```
a , new_process , b , c
```

in this case the `new_process` will execute after the current process `a` exit from the event loop. then b,c will execute.

and other hand

`setImmediate` , when you run this the new process add at the end of queue . Like this

```
a , b, c , new_process
```

So now when all a,b,c are finished then the `new_process` is execute .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I asked 'What means I/O in context `nextTick`/`setImmediate`?' As I see from your answer these `a , b, c` functions are inputs and when `a` will be executed it will out from queue so we can call this queue as `I/O queue`. Please correct me some one if it's not right